# Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, json, rest

I want to Return A json from a Method. But i appear to be missing something

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace RESTBrowserGET
{
    public class BrowseRESTGet
    {
        public static string GETRESTSimulator(string restUrl, string reqMethod)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restUrl);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            //return responseString;
            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonObj>(responseString);
            return jsonObj;
        }
    }
}
```

Thats my code. Now apparently i am missing something. Please what do I appear to be missing? 
I am getting this Error :

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

There appear to be something i am missing? Please i need some form of Clarification

**Edit**

Code Looks Like this Now

```
public class BrowseRESTGet
{
    public static JObject GETRESTSimulator(string restUrl, string reqMethod)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restUrl);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        //return responseString;
        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
        return jsonObj;
    }
}
```

Now i am Fighting with this As errror

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'
```

**Edit**

Code Edited to

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace RESTBrowserGET
{
    public class BrowseRESTGet
    {
        public static JObject GETRESTSimulator(string restUrl, string reqMethod)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restUrl);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            //return responseString;
            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseString);
            return jsonObj;
        }
    }
}
```

**Latest Edit**

```
public static JObject GETRESTSimulator(string restUrl, string reqMethod)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restUrl);
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: dies this help you? `JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);`

Comment: Not at all @viveknuna

Comment: Is it giving any error?

Comment: change `GETRESTSimulator` return type to  `JObject` or  return `responseString`.

Comment: @viveknuna, yes

Comment: @GuruStron, How?

Comment: @Husseiny you have to tell the error, otherwise how can we know the issue?

Comment: `public static JObject GETRESTSimulator(....`

Comment: @GuruStron, Pls see Edited Code

Comment: @Husseiny `var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);` -> `var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseString);` or `var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(responseString);`

Comment: @GuruStron, Fails returns this Error Unable to cast Object of type Newtonsoft.json.Linq.array to type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Object i have Updated the code too

Comment: @Husseiny *i want to return a string containing the Json Objects* -  then just `return responseString;` with original method signature `public static JObject GETRESTSimulator(`. You don't need to deserialize.

Comment: @GuruStron tells me cannot convert String to Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' thats the latest Error now

Comment: Edited the Code to what I have now..

Answer (score 1):

`responseString` IS a string, so there is no need to deserialise it.

Further to your response, I would recommend deserialising the data straight away rather than passing around JObjects.

```
    public static T GETRESTSimulator<T>(string restUrl, string reqMethod)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restUrl);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        //return responseString;
        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
        return jsonObj;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
       MyDto1 response1 = GETRESTSimulator<MyDto1>("url", "POST");

       MyDto2 response2 = GETRESTSimulator<MyDto2>("Url2", "GET");

    }
```

Comment: i want it to return the JSON Objects so I can use the information from the REST api to other parts of the Application i am developing

Comment: Cannot convert type T to string, thats what it says now

Comment: The function return type must also be `T`.

Answer (score 1):

your method returns a string and in the return instruction you use the variable jsonObj which is a JObject.

You can use the ToString() method on it if it is implemented correctly.

However, I don't understand what you mean by returning a json from a method. Do you want to return a string containing the json ? Or do you want to return an object with properties matching the one in the json ?

Comment: i want to return a string containing the Json Objects